# Using sin and cos to make a circle move in a circle in java

Tags: java, object, geometry

I am creating a program that has a circle object that moves in a circular motion around a canvas. I have the circle and render classes created and am just working on the moving now. This is my code so far and it is unfortunately not working. I am not sure where to go from here or if I am on the right track.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Rotation
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    int x;
    int y;
    int radius = 30;
    double step = .01;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Render render = new Render();
    Circle c = new Circle(150,150,radius);

    render.addCircle(c);
    render.draw();
    double angle = 0.0;

   while (angle < step)
   {

     x = (int)(c.getX()+Math.cos(angle*2*(Math.PI))*radius);
    y = (int)(c.getY()+Math.sin(angle*2*(Math.PI))*radius);

    c.setX(x);
    c.setY(y);

    render.redraw();
   }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, your while loop is wrong.
If you stubstitute the values

```
while(angle < step)
```

becomes

```
while(0 < 0.01)
```

But that doesn't matter, since you're not actually incrementing angle anywhere. Perhaps you should increment the angle by the step and do it until the circle is full (i.e. 2*Math.PI).

Comment: +1. Almost.  Make it `while(angle < 1)`, because we multiply by 2pi within the code.

Comment: Well that's a curious and ineffective way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

`while(angle < step)` is actual a dead loop.And another thing ,you never use the variable input which is initiated by `Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);`